# How do I make a singe $.getJSON call based on one select change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have several dynamically rendered tr tags that contain select tags. I want to be able to update a single select based upon another select in the same tr tag.  What's currently happening is that when I make a select change in one tr tag, subsequently all other selects are updated in each tr tag.  Here is an example of my code.

HTML:

```
 <tr>
     <td>
        <select>Main</select>
     </td>
     <td>
        <select>Updated from Main</select>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>
        <select>Main</select>
     </td>
     <td>
        <select>Updated from Main</select>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Jquery:

```
 var monitorProCodeChange = function() {
// monitor select code change
$("select[name=prodCode]").change(function() {
    $("tr").each(function() {
        alert("change event fired");

        var prodCode = $(this).find("select[name=prodCode]");
        var product = $(this).find("select[name=product]");

        $.getJSON("/api/product/getproductbyid/" + prodCode.val(), function(data) {
            product.append(
                $("<option/>").attr("value", data.Id).text(data.ProductDescription));
        });
    });
});
};
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way I'm iterating through the tr tags, but I can't figure out how to make each row independent of one another.

Comment: Like in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5MfrV/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that `.each()` function

Try this way -

```
var monitorProCodeChange = function () {
    // monitor select code change
    $("select[name=prodCode]").change(function () {
        alert("change event fired");
        var prodCode = $(this);
        var product = $(this).closest('tr').find("select[name=product]");
        $.getJSON("/api/product/getproductbyid/" + prodCode.val(), function (data) {
            product.append(
            $("<option/>").attr("value", data.Id).text(data.ProductDescription));
        });

    });
};
```